# How to get the object value from a Map?

Tags: java

```java
Map<String, Object> subSource2 = (Map<String, Object>)departmentPHSSuportEmail.get("SubSource");
List<Map<String , Object>> myMap2  = (List<Map<String , Object>>)subSource2.get("value");
Map<String,Object> subSourceMap3 = myMap2.get(0);
String value = (String)subSourceMap3.get("value");
```

Here, I won't specify the value as `String`. It may be any type. So when I'm casting it as a String only `String` values should be accepted and no other datatypes can be accepted.So is there any way to change the below code?

```java
String value = (String)subSourceMap3.get("value");
```

to other one to accept all other datatypes.

Comment: "only string values should be accepted" - what do you mean by accepted?

Comment: Not sure whether this is what you're looking for: `Object value = subSourceMap3.get("value");`?

Comment: I´m not sure what you mean by that. Your method surely returns `Object` as of the maps declaration. If you know that the values are `Sring`, you can cast to `String`. f they are integers, cast to `Integer`. If you don´t know the type stay on `Object`, you don´t even need to cast that as it allready **is** of that type.

Comment: What's the point of using a strongly typed language only to work around typing variables?

Comment: @Nicktar - and that is the real question.

Comment: This design pattern is not ideal. Why not replace your `Object` parameter with a class that stores the values you are after? For example `Map<String, SubSourceData>`, where `SubSourceData` could contain the attributes with the types you want to store?

Comment: itemjson.setTest(val.get("sample")==JSONObject.NULL ? null : (Double) val.get("sample")); Here test is of type double and the data type is fixed .But the datatype of sample may varies based on the json.Now the datatype is double.so casting as Double...But in some case we passed the value of type Integer and so well..I have same code with multiple jsons..So how it is possible to get the values of diferent datatypes in the same code

Answer (score 2):

If you can have any types associated with that key in the Map and want only `String` values to be cast to `String`, you need to check the type before casting:

```
Object rawValue = subSourceMap3.get("value");
if (rawValue instanceof String) {
    String value = (String) rawValue;
    // do what you want with the String value
} else if (rawValue instanceof Long) { // or whatever else
    // cast to Long
} else {
    // throw an exception for unknown types or do nothing
}
```

However, if your code is only able to handle String representations, you can just call `.toString()` on the `rawValue` above (except when it's `null`!) and not care about its actual type.

Answer (score 1):

subSourceMap3 is your Map and get() returns the Object you want.

```
Object yourObj = subSourceMap3.get("value");
```

Without any cast.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
Object value = subSourceMap3.get("value");
```

Or if you can cast it to any object or custom object

```
YourCustomObject value = (YourCustomObject)subSourceMap3.get("value");
```

Hope this might help.

For the case mentioned in comments you can use below code snippet and add conditions according to datatype you receive :-

```
    if(val.get("sample") instanceof Double) {
        itemjson.setTest((Double) val.get("sample"));
    }else if(val.get("sample") instanceof Integer) {
        itemjson.setTest((Integer) val.get("sample"));
    }else if(val.get("sample") instanceof Float) {
        itemjson.setTest((Float) val.get("sample"));
    }else if(val.get("sample")==JSONObject.NULL){
        itemjson.setTest(null);
    }
```

Comment: itemjson.setTest(val.get("sample")==JSONObject.NULL ? null : (Double) val.get("sample")); Here test is of type double and the data type is fixed .But the datatype of sample may varies based on the json.Now the datatype is double.so casting as Double...But in some case we passed the value of type Integer and so well..I have same code with multiple jsons..So how it is possible to get the values of diferent datatypes in the same code